# Autoscaling instance web & database server

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, web, instance, autoscaling

I had an interview a couple days ago and they asked me something that I dont know and I would like to ask you to see what would you do.
Scenario: an AWS instance with a web service and database running inside. How would I manage in case of autoscaling? Knowing that there are no problem with the web service if it replicates (to manage the web performance, for example) but how would I solve with the database service on it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reliably auto scale for performance on this type of dual service instance beyond one (1)  single instance. You cannot autoscale horizontally (2+) for web performance reasons, because you only ever want a single database instance.

If availabilty/100% uptime of the web app is not critical, then an ASG with a desired size of one (1) max would provide automatic replacement in case of failure. A failure of any of the two services, or instance termination, would replace the single instance automatically, with some limited downtime.

If you need to scale horizontally to two or more instances, for web performance reasons, then you need to factor out the database into its own instance, or migrate it to RDS.